# Meteor Tabular using external api

Tags: mongodb, meteor, tabular

I am using `aldeed:tabular` for meteor. I have it set up to use my local mongo. However, I am having trouble finding a way to create a table through an external API.

How can I set up tabular to do this?

```
TabularTables.Transfers = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "Books",
  collection: Transfers, // can I use an external API for this?
  ...
});
```